# Problem with picasso, don't get picture from url

Tags: java, android, picasso

I want to display a picture of a url on a server in my app which is password protected.

Viewing from a public directory is possible, unfortunately not an option for me.

Here is my code, I have checked the path and access data, unfortunately the image is not shown to me and I do not get an error message despite the listener.
Does anyone see the reason.

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder ( )
                .authenticator ( new Authenticator ( ) {
                    @Override
                    public Request authenticate(Route route , Response response) throws IOException {
                        String credential = Credentials.basic ( user , pass );
                        return response.request ( ).newBuilder ( )
                                .header ( "Authorization" , credential )
                                .build ( );
                    }
                } ).build ( );

        System.out.println ( okHttpClient.followSslRedirects ( ) );
        System.out.println ( okHttpClient.connectionSpecs ( ) );

        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder ( this );
        builder.downloader ( new OkHttp3Downloader ( okHttpClient ) );
        builder.listener ( new Picasso.Listener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso , Uri uri , Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace ( );
                System.out.println ( "Fehler : " + exception.toString ( ) );
            }
        } );
        Picasso picasso = builder.build ( );


        picasso.get ( )
                .load ( domain + graffilepath )
//              .load ( "https://www.xxxxx.de/info.jpg")
                .error ( R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground )
                .into ( infoimage );
    }
```

Comment: Have you added permission for Internet?

Comment: Yes, I think in other case no picture was displayed on second load in code ?